# extra line at the ends of equal in tikzcd and confuse about font size of label of phantom arrow

Tags: fontsize, arrows, tikz-cd, adobe, sumatrapdf

1. When I choose the equal as the style of arrow, I find that there two very light extra line at the two ends of equal symbols. Maybe it depends on the PDF reader. I can find the extra lines when I use SumatraPDF reader and the PDF viewer in Chrome. But when I use Adobe reader, the extra lines disappear. So the extra light lines do exist? Or this is just a bug of PDF reader?
2. When I use the phantom option for an arrow, the font size of label of this arrow seems to be changed. The font size is no longer scriptstyle. Of course, one can use `\scriptstyle`. So this is just what tikz want it to be? And why tikz prefers it to be displystyle. And what is the advantage of it.

The following is a simple example.

```
`\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=1.5em]
1\rar[phantom,"1"] &\circ\rar[equal] &\circ
\end{tikzcd}\]`
```

Then the first picture is what I see using SumatraPDF reader, and the second is what I see using Adobe reader. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the equal is made using two rectangles, one black and one white. You are probably seeing rounding error due to different rendering engines. Not sure if it is possible to do anything about it (I have observed it as well, does the line still appear in Sumatra if you zoom in really close?)

Comment: @daleif One can place an equal symbol beside. When zoom the page in Sumatra, the difference is clear. If the page is not so small that one can't distinguish the two lines of equal, the difference can also be noticed. Maybe under some special scale of the page, one or the other extra light line will disappear, but it is only by chance. Also, I noticed that in some special case and special scale of page, one line of the 'normal' line of `\Rightarrow` may disappear by chance. I don't think that will be a question. But this seems not that case.

Comment: I tried also Stduviewer, and opened it with Edge, Chrome. The line will both appear. It seems that just Adobe reader in PC can render it well. Even with the Adobe reader app in android, the line will appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Two be sure not to have the issue, whichever is the viewer, you can draw two `dash` lines side by side instead of one `equal` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
With \texttt{equal} option there is the viewer issue:
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=1.5em]
1\rar[phantom,"1"] &\circ\rar[equal] &\circ
\end{tikzcd}\]

With two \texttt{dash} lines put side by side there is not:
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=1.5em]
1\rar[phantom,"1"] &\circ\rar[dash,yshift=1pt]\rar[dash,yshift=-1pt] &\circ
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. From the tikz-cd manual:

> `/tikz/commutative diagrams/phantom`             (style, no value)
>   Creates an
>   invisible arrow. Labels to this arrow are not invisible. They will be
>   anchored at their center and typeset in full size (i.e., with
>   `\textstyle`). To get smaller labels, as in ordinary arrows, use the
>   `\scriptstyle` command.